# Split dataframe into relatively even chunks according to length

Tags: python, pandas

I have to create a function which would split provided dataframe into chunks of needed size. For instance if dataframe contains 1111 rows, I want to be able to specify chunk size of 400 rows, and get three smaller dataframes with sizes of 400, 400 and 311. Is there a convenience function to do the job? What would be the best way to store and iterate over sliced dataframe?

Example DataFrame

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

test = pd.concat([pd.Series(np.random.rand(1111)), pd.Series(np.random.rand(1111))], axis = 1)
```

Comment: You can just get the index ranges using `test.index[::400]` and use this to slice the df: `first = test.iloc[:400] second = test.iloc[400:800] third = test.iloc[800]`

Comment: I have more than 50 files with >50k rows, I think I will have to generate additional index in a loop and use df.groupby()

Comment: You can look at [`sklearn train_test_split`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html) also

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can take the [floor division](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/floor_division.html) of a sequence up to the amount of rows in the dataframe, and use it to [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) splitting the dataframe into equally sized chunks:

```
n = 400
for g, df in test.groupby(np.arange(len(test)) // n):
    print(df.shape)
# (400, 2)
# (400, 2)
# (311, 2)
```

Comment: how can I put each df produced from each iteration in a new df to use later

Comment: @Kimchi You can get it from the `groupby` object `(test.groupby(np.arange(len(test)) // n))`. If you assign that to a variable, you can then call `.groups()` to get a dictionary of `{group id:[dataframe index ids]}`. You can then use the group ids to retrieve each dataframe by calling `.get_group(group_id)` on the `groupby` object.

Answer (score 12):

A more pythonic way to break large dataframes into smaller chunks based on fixed number of rows is to use list comprehension:

```
n = 400  #chunk row size
list_df = [test[i:i+n] for i in range(0,test.shape[0],n)]

[i.shape for i in list_df]
```

Output:

```
[(400, 2), (400, 2), (311, 2)]
```

Comment: how can I use this result afterwards? In my case, I have used your code to save my dataframe in chunks. I have code that creates a tfDIF oh my pandas dataframe, how can I apply this code so that my TfDIF is calculated not on the entire dataframe, but on each one of these chunks instead so that I avoid Memory Error?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the chunks to be 400? Why not 370-370-371 for a more even split?

If this works for you, then you can use numpy's [array_split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) function. Instead of a chunk size, you give it the number of chunks you want and it'll break it up evenly for you. You can specify 400 as a guide for the final number of chunks with `ceil(len(test) / 400)` chunks

```py
from math import ceil
import numpy as np

np.array_split(test, ceil(len(test) / 400))
```

This'll give you a list of 3, evenly-sized dataframes.