# How to split pandas dataframe based on byte size

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, amazon-redshift

I want to insert data from a huge pandas DataFrame onto Redshift. However, when I try to execute the insert statement, I get the following error:

> ERROR: Statement is too large. Statement Size: 152681090 bytes.
>   Maximum Allowed: 16777216 bytes

To overcome this, I want to split the dataframe into chunks that are within the allowed size and execute separate insert statements for each chunk. How exactly do I divide the dataframe into chunks of rows that are within the limit of 16777216 bytes?

If that is not possible, is there any other way I can insert data from such a large dataframe onto Redshift?

Thanks!

Comment: check this answer for the rows 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/33368088/2027457

Comment: Thanks, I saw that. But I do not know how many rows I want. I only know that each chunk should have a maximum of 16777216 bytes. Each row is likely to have a varied byte size.

Comment: ok, than you can use the to_sql for writing and define the chunk size there as following:  data.to_sql('df', engine, chunksize=10000)

Comment: or you can loop thru each row and add to your redshift

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-sql

Comment: also do you use boto3 ?

Comment: Thank you, I am inserting into an existing table, not creating a new one. I will just insert in batches of 'x' rows. I'll probably ballpark the x, and handle any exceptions. I am using psycopg2.

Comment: I would suggest to use s3 and load to redshift, I used this way and is easy and "safe".

Answer (score 0):

```
DataFrame.to_sql(name, con, flavor=None, schema=None, if_exists=’fail’, index=True, index_label=None, chunksize=None, dtype=None)[source]
```

[source to documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)

Per documentation you can specify the chunksize so you can use 5-10k and see how does work.

```
chunksize : int, default None
If not None, then rows will be written in batches of this size at a time. If None, all rows will be written at once.
```

2. Another option is to use this wrapper so the intermediate is **s3**:
   [source code of the wrapper](https://gist.github.com/ajsmith007/d1adb79e152f5f23503b)
3. so if you load into existing table than you can follow this steps: data from n**ew_table**(*chunk data table*) you insert into existing one (Used this type of **"temp"** table and loaded very quick, did preprocessing too, *redshift* does create temp tables when does do the update and this is supper fast)

P.S. if you provide code example and data I can spin a cluster and provide detailed results but current info will help with **chunk** question.