# How to average a column over fixed intervals?

Tags: python, pandas

here is the situation:

I have a dataframe containing a column with values ranging from 0 to 2000 and I would like to compute the average and standard deviation for each interval of width 200.
I know how to do it over time intervals with the resample method but I can't find how to perform this with a float column.

Thank you all very much for your help!

Comment: df.groupby(df.reset_index().index//200).agg(['mean', 'std'])

Comment: or if you want to do so for *every* 200 sub-intervals, have a look at `df.rolling(200)`.

Answer (score 0):

If name of your dataset is `data`:

```
data.groupby(data.index // 200).mean()
```

[Answer taken from this source.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367142/split-dataframe-into-relatively-even-chunks-according-to-length/33368088)