# Python iterate over a float array or list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, floating-point

I have a Pandas dataframe and i Need to create a function to a specific column in it which has only Floating Point values. i can retrieve the column and convert it to list or Array. But Once i use for loop Iteration for the Floating column it doesnt work. Is there anyway to do it.

```
batchsize=10
for i in dataset['timeslices4profilerdataprocess50_c0us']:
    for j in range(0,i,batchsize): 
        print(j)


TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

How can i do it with

> np.linspace() or np.arange()

or with any Option?Any alternative for range Operation to perform with floats?

Comment: is your indentation intentional??

Comment: Do you wish to apply a function over batches of pandas rows? see this [SE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33368088/2456179) and this [SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56218003/pandas-dataframe-operation-per-batch-of-rows)

Comment: You could replace `range` with `np.arange(0, i, i/batchsize)` and it shall work. Just remember that the `i` value is not included in such a case.

Comment: @RunTheGauntlet this works and prints values over the Array length but i need exact values from the column to be iterated over for a certain condition

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand what exactly you want.
can you explain a bit.

range() function only takes integer value.
"i" that you are passing is float value which is why your code is failing.

Comment: Please write this up as a comment. Not an answer.

Comment: i wanted to create a function to delete repeating values in certain intervals in the columns.My columns values are not int. i cannot round of also

Comment: can you give a example.

Comment: if you want to iterate over the value, you should not use range() function.
Convert the datatype to str and the you can iterate it char by char

Comment: @PrashantKumar, sorry man, I'm new to this. didn't know if i can add a comment instead of answering

Comment: @AmitKumar My dataset has values repeated for every 10 rows. i Need to Keep the first value and delete all the other 9 rows. and on 11th row it should be Kept and others  until 20 should be deleted. I Need this to be performed in a function and for that i Need for loop Iteration.

Comment: can't you use groupby logic and keep first row?
dataset=dataset.groupby('timeslices4profilerdataprocess50_c0us').first().reset_index()

Comment: thankyou. but I Need duplicates also as I mentioned.for eg. my value would be 0.8 on first row and 0.8 again on 11th row. i Need both. and i Need to remove values between that and should repeat until the end.like for this column i Need to Keep values of 1,11,21,etc. and delete others

Comment: ```
def keep_first(column,batchSize):
    return_list=[]
    for idx,value in enumerate(column):
        if (idx+1)%batchSize==1:
            return_list.append(True)
        else:
            return_list.append(False)
    return return_list  
df=pd.DataFrame(list([[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,6],[1,6],[1,6],[1,6],[1,6],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]]))
df.columns=['a','b']
df['c']=keep_first(df.b.to_list(),5)
df=df[df.c==True] ```
See If this helps.

Comment: @AmitKumar This works.thankyou. But do you have any idea of doing this Operation over entire dataframe?